# How do I call two firestore collection in flutter i.e the message collection and the user collection

Tags: flutter, dart

I am having this issue on how to call the last message sent from the message Collection in firestore in flutter coupled with the image and username of the sender of the message from the user Collection and display those data to user Interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, in Firestore, you try to make `read` operation easier.

Based on your requirements, you should probably store the display name and avatar of the sender within the `message` document in Firestore.

This means that when you create a new `message`, you need access to the `user` to store this information.
This also means that if the `user` changes her display name and/or avatar, you will have to modify all of her `messages` in Firestore. This is usually done with a Cloud Function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers, please can you give an insight on how to carry in cloud function, something like and example that i can follow up.thanks in anticipation

Comment: Have a look here for explanation about syncing denormalized data [https://youtu.be/77XmRDtOL7c?t=293]. By the way, the whole series about Get to know Firestore is really good. Check also this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53278365/firebase-cloud-functions-make-queries-on-collection

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was really helpful